# Query for sorting a date that is inside another object in firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a chat in angularjs where I have a chat list view and a chat view.

What I'm trying to do is sorting my chat list to show the most recent chat on top using Firebase and JS, I did my research but all of the questions I found they have the date directly as a child but inside my DB my date is inside a 'lastMessage' key. My dates are the following format.

```
date: 1528417493034
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

My structure is the following:

```
"Users": {
"nCsXbTl8CcXvoviuL5Tt7kiV6Bn1" : {
      "contacts" : {
        "VN9AFnn4uXgDfoir8DWHnw54zrJ3" : {
          "email" : "test@test.com",
          "lastMessage" : {
            "date" : 1528417493034,
            "senderId" : "VN9AFnn4uXgDfoir8DWHnw54zrJ3",
            "status" : "success",
            "text" : "Yes?",
            "type" : "text",
            "uid" : "1528417493034VN9AFnn4uXgDfoir8DWHnw54zrJ3"
          },
          "name" : "test"
        },
        "cHuR26YaSgbO7ahSVLg1XG5HYer2" : {
          "email" : "aaa@aaa.com",
          "lastMessage" : {
            "date" : 1528417068249,
            "senderId" : "cHuR26YaSgbO7ahSVLg1XG5HYer2",
            "status" : "success",
            "text" : "Trigeeeers?",
            "type" : "text",
            "uid" : "1528417068249cHuR26YaSgbO7ahSVLg1XG5HYer2"
          },
          "name" : "aaa"
        }
      }
}
```

My chat list view is the following:

```
<div layout="row" class="main-chat-container" layout-wrap>
<div class="list-container" flex="30">
    <div class="chat-header">
        <p>Lista de Chats</p>
    </div>
    <div class="chats-list">
        <div class="chats-header">
            <p>Usuarios</p>
        </div>
        <div class="chats" ng-repeat="chat in chats">
            <div class="email-container" ng-click="setUserData(chat)" ng-class="styleData.email == chat.email ? 'new-background' : ''">
                <a>{{chat.email}}</a> <p ng-show="counter > 1">{{testData.number}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class-"chat-container" flex="70">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

And the controller is the following

```
app.controller('chatController', function (currentAuth, $scope, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {

$scope.chats = [];

$scope.getContactsList = function(){
    var listRef = firebase.database().ref('Users').child(currentAuth.uid).child('contacts');
    var test = firebase.database().ref('Users').child(currentAuth.uid).child('contacts');
    var listArray = $firebaseArray(listRef);
    var testArray = $firebaseArray(test);
    $scope.chats = listArray;

    console.log("TEST ARRAY IS ");
    console.log(testArray);



}

$scope.getContactsList();
});
```

Comment: Your code and your sample data structure don't match. E.g. there is no `contacts` in the sample. Instead of showing a data model, show an actual piece of the JSON that you're trying to query (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I changed it, do you know how to query this? Thanks in advance. @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1):

To so a users contacts on the timestamp of their last message, you'd do something like this:

```
var userRef = firebase.database().ref('Users').child(currentAuth.uid)
var contactsQuery = userRef.child('contacts').orderByChild("lastMessage/date");
```

Note that this will give you the contacts in chronological order, so you will have to reverse the result in your client.

Alternatively some folks keep an inverted value in a separate property in their database, e.g.

```
    "VN9AFnn4uXgDfoir8DWHnw54zrJ3" : {
      "email" : "test@test.com",
      "lastMessage" : {
        "date" : 1528417493034,
        "invertedDate" : -1528417493034,
        "senderId" : "VN9AFnn4uXgDfoir8DWHnw54zrJ3",
```

Since this `invertedDate` value is inverted, ordering on that property would give you the contacts in reverse chronological order, so that you don't have to reverse them in the client.